# How to make the definition of the constructor outside the header file?

Tags: c++, constructor, inline

I have this constructor in the header file:

```
class Fan {
  Id id;
  string name;
  Age age;
public:
  Fan(Id id, string name, Age age);
};
```

And this definition in the .cpp

```
Fan::Fan(Id id, string name="someone", Age age=0) : id(id), name(name),
  age(age), status(disconnected)
{
  if(id<0 || age<0) {
    throw BadParams();
  }
}
```

I have this notes: (mtm is the namespace)

```
..\Fan.h:60:2: note: mtm::Fan::Fan(mtm::Id, std::string, mtm::Age)
..\Fan.h:60:2: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
..\Fan.h:47:7: note: mtm::Fan::Fan(const mtm::Fan&)
..\Fan.h:47:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

I tried to inline before the both the declaration and the definition and get this errors:

```
..\Fan.h:60:9: note: mtm::Fan::Fan(mtm::Id, std::string, mtm::Age)
..\Fan.h:60:9: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
..\Fan.h:47:7: note: mtm::Fan::Fan(const mtm::Fan&)
..\Fan.h:47:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
..\Fan.h:60:9: warning: inline function 'mtm::Fan::Fan(mtm::Id, std::string, mtm::Age)' used but never defined [enabled by default]
```

Comment: Default arguments are specified in the function's *declaration*, not in its definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the default arguments in the declaration (i.e. in the .h file), not in the .cpp file.

i.e.:

```
class Fan {
public:
   Fan(Id id, string name="someone", Age age=0);
};
```

Comment: should it bee inline?

Comment: Only if you want it to be. It doesn't *have to*.